# How to work with css position absolute and flex end in React native

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I need to make a view top of text element. And the element inside View should be ordered bottom to top

```
three
two
one
text element
```

The text element should not be pushed down if number of top elements increases. How to achieve this?

I have tried like this. Got text element x,y, width, height by onlayout event

```
<>
  <View>
    <Text>Text</Text>
  </View>
  <View
    style={{
      top: textEl?.top - 20,
      left: textE?.left,
      position: 'absolute',
      flexDirection:'column',
      justifyContent:'flex-end'
    }}>
    <View>
      <View>
        <Text>one</Text>
      </View>
      <View>
        <Text>two</Text>
      </View>
      <View>
        <Text>three</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  </View>
</>;
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS : `flex-wrap: wrap-revers`
React: `flexWrap: 'wrap-revers'`

Comment: Not working @Dhruvi Makvana, Can't  stack view bottom to top